# Errors in main.cpp after delcaration of .h files

Tags: c++, header, include, project

here's my problem:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<memory>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sstream>
#include<utility>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>

#include "classes.h"
#include "firstfunction.h"
#include "secondfunction.h"
#include "third function.h"

using namespace std;


int main(){
  // do cool stuff
}
```

but when i compile  I get the errors (all at the same line, the one of using namespace)

error: only constructor take member initializer
error: expected identified before 'using'
error: expected '{' before using

if I try to remove "using namespace std" I still get the same with 'int' instead of using.

the rest of the code seems to compile without errors! do you have any ideas?

Comment: If that's your only source file, then you have an error in one of the header files.

Comment: The first thing you should have done is comment out all of those header files that are yours, comment out the "cool stuff" in `main` and recompile.  Then if the code compiles, introduce each one back into the program and recompile until the compilation fails.

Comment: More than likely the issue is in `third function.h`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to remove the space between in "third function.h"? I don't know, but maybe changing the name of the file to "thirdfunction.h" or to "third_function.h" would work. C++ is a really bad guy when you have to deal with blank spaces. Also, you should check the implementations inside your .h files (from "classes.h" to "third function.h"), cause the error could be in one of them. I should look first if it works changing the name of "third function.h" and then deep-looking into your other .h files...